# Why is the IWorkspaceRoot I get is null?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developping an eclipse plugin, but when I use IWorkspaceRoot to get root, it always return null. Do you guys have any ideas about this? Thank you in advance!

```
IWorkspaceRoot rootWorkspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
```

Comment: Exactly how and where are you running this code? The workspace root will only be set up properly when running the plug-in as part of an Eclipse RCP.

Comment: I took over this project from someone else, and it goes wrong here, so I am looking for some possible situations.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to say what is wrong. At a guess you are not running the code as an Eclipse plug-in - you need to use 'Run As > Eclipse Application', running as a plain Java program won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions:

Either `ResourcesPlugin` will be null or Workspace (`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`) is not created.

The workspace is manipulated using resource handles. Resource handles are lightweight pointers to a particular project, folder, or file in the workspace. You can create a resource handle without creating a resource, and resources can exist regardless of whether any handles exist that point to them. To create a resource, you first have to create a resource handle and then tell it to create the resource. The following snippet uses resource handles to create a project, a folder, and a file.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
IProject project  = root.getProject("MyProject");
IFolder folder = project.getFolder("Folder1");
IFile file = folder.getFile("hello.txt");
//at this point, no resources have been created
if (!project.exists()) project.create(null);
if (!project.isOpen()) project.open(null);
if (!folder.exists()) 
    folder.create(IResource.NONE, true, null);
if (!file.exists()) {
    byte[] bytes = "File contents".getBytes();
    InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    file.create(source, IResource.NONE, null);
}
```

This example defensively checks that the resource doesn’t already exist before trying to create it. This kind of defensive programming is a good idea because an exception is thrown if you try to create a resource that already exists. This way, the example can be run more than once in the same workspace without causing an error. The null parameters to the creation methods should be replaced by a progress monitor in a real application.

Comment: Your code assumes that `root` is not null, the question is saying that it is `null`.